# separatorColor property doesn't return default color on iOS9 beta4

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

separatorColor property doesn't return default color on iOS9 beta4. Any idea?

print separatorColor on iOS8
[image]

print separatorColor on iOS9 beta4
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add separator view in your tableView using

```
 UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 3)];/// change size as you need.       
 separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];// you can also put image here
 [cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];
```

and then give background color to view and then check separatorColor.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need a way to get default separator color and use it on another view. not to change the default separator.